# Changing the LSB to 1 in a 4 bit integer via C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am receiving a number N where N is a 4-bit integer and I need to change its LSB to 1 without changing the other 3 bits in the number using C.

Basically, all must read XXX1.

So lets say `n = 2`, the binary would be `0010`. I would change the LSB to 1 making the number `0011`.

I am struggling with finding a combination of operations that will do this. I am working with: `!`, `~`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `<<`, `>>`, `+`, `-`, `=`.

This has really been driving me crazy and I have been playing around with `>>`/`<<` and `~` and starting out with `0xF`.

Comment: Yes but I don't want the answer. I want guidance.

Comment: @JohnLanz: This is too simple to offer guidance without spelling it out.

Comment: `n | ~n` will set all the bits to 1, not only the LSB

Comment: @Marcelo I didn't know.. I thought I had to use shifts plus other operators, I was making it too complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
number |= 1;
```

This should set the LSB to 1 regardless of what the number is. Why? Because the bitwise OR (`|`) operator does exactly what its name suggests: it logical ORs the two numbers' bits. So if you have, say, 1010b and 1b (10 and 1 in decimal), then the operator does this:

```
   1 0 1 0
OR 0 0 0 1
=  1 0 1 1
```

And that's exactly what you want.

For your information, the

```
number |= 1;
```

statement is equivalent to

```
number = number | 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `x = x | 0x01;` to set the LSB to `1`

A visualization

```
      ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?
   OR
      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
      ----------------------
      ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  1
```

Therefore other bits will stay the same except the LSB is set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use the bitwise or operator `|`.  It looks at two numbers bit by bit, and returns the number generated by performing an OR with each bit.

```
int n = 2;
n = n | 1;
printf("%d\n", n); // prints the number 3
```

In binary, 2 = 0010, 3 = 0011, and 1 = 0001

```
   0010
OR 0001
-------
   0011
```

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is not `0`

```
n | !!n
```

works.

If `n` is `0`, then `!n` is what you want.

---

UPDATE

The fancy one liner :P

```
n = n ? n | !!n : !n;
```

Comment: By `!!`, you mean bitwise complement, right? Cause thats `~` in C.

Comment: @Linuxios Not exactly, `!` operator turns non-zero value to `0` and `0` to exactly `1`.

Comment: @Linuxios: he does mean `!`. For non-zero `n`, `!!n` is `1`, which is the right thing to put in the `|`. It's just a very funny way of generating a 1, that (as stated in this answer) 
doesn't work in the case where `n` is `0`.

Comment: @SteveJessop I assume the OP tries to make the LSB 1 without introducing constant explicitly. If it is not the original mind, ignore my answer. :)

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea: ah, in the case you should say "if `n` is `0`, then `!n` is what you want", to avoid using the constant in that case either. I'm all for funniness as long as it's deliberate. `n = n ? n | !!n : !n;`. But I don't think that is what the questioner wants, I think he's just stalled on understanding bitwise ops at all.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. And update the answer according to your comment. Thanks :).

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea: That's a cool trick! I love when I get to learn more about bitwise hacking in C. Thanks!